# How do I require and provide clojure files?

Tags: file, import, clojure

I have a set of functions saved in a clojure file.

How do I Provide selected set of functions and then import these functions in my other file?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have a few options.

If it’s just a file (not in a package) then in your files, you can just use `load`.  If your file was named “fun.clj”, you would just use the name of the file without the extension:

```
 (load "fun")
```

(provided `fun.clj` was on your classpath).  Or

```
 (load "files/fun")
```

if it wasn’t on your classpath but in the `files` directory.

Or you could use `load-file` and pass it the location of your file:

```
(load-file "./files/fun.clj")
```

If you wanted to namespace them (put them in a package), then you’d put the `ns` macro at the beginning of your file, again put it on your classpath.  Then you could load it via `use` or `require`.

Here are the docs for the functions I’ve described:

- [`load`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/load)
- [`load-file`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/load-file)
- [`ns`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ns)
- [`use`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/use)
- [`require`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/require)

Comment: I am sorry but I still have some problem. I have a file called stopwords.clj and Autotag.clj. I want to import stopwords into Autotag. When I put (load "stopwords"), it says "Could not locate stopwords__init.class or stopwords.clj on classpath:" even though I have stopwords and Autotag in the same folder. I am sorry but I am a complete newbie. Please help me.

Comment: The current directory is probably not on your classpath so clojure can't 'see' it. Put stopwords.clj somewhere on your classpath (or change your classpath to include ".").

Comment: Sorry, don't know.  emacs user over here.

Comment: Thank you, Seth. I've been banging my head for an hour trying to figure this out (no thanks to the PragProg book, which is anything but pragmatic)

Answer (score 4):

Besides "load"ing source files, you can also use the leiningen "checkout dependencies" feature.  If you have two leiningen projects, say, project A requires B (provider).  In the root directory of project A, create a directory called "checkouts".  Inside "/checkouts" make a symbolic link to the root directory of project B.

```
- project A
  - project.clj
  - checkouts
    - symlink to project B
  - src
  - test
```

in project A's project.clj, declare project B as a dependency in the :dependencies section as if it were a project in clojars.org.  E.g.

```
(defproject project-a
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
               [project-b "0.1.0"]])
```

The thing though is, you have to go into project B and type:

```
lein install
```

That will compile project B's files into a jar file, which will appear in your ~/.m2 directory, which is kind of like your local clojars.org cache.

Once you set all this up, in your *.clj src file(s) of project A, you can "require" project B files in the normal way, as if it were from clojars.org:

```
(ns project-a.core
  (:require [project-b.core :as pb])
```

This way, you can refer to functions in your project-b.core the usual way like this:

```
pb/myfunction1
```

In my opinion, this is a pretty good way to share libraries and data between Leiningen projects while trying keep each Leiningen project as independent, self-contained, and minimal as possible.

Answer (score 1):

This one solved my problem and I have looked through countless other issues here so I would like to clarify.

The easiest way in emacs (on linux) is to do something like this:

```
java -cp "lib/*":. clojure.main -e "(do (require 'swank.swank) (swank.swank/start-repl))"
```

(note the "lib/*":. given to -cp

Then you can use M-x slime-connect to connect with this instance.

Don't know if it's required, but I have read that it's a good idea to use the same version of clojure, clojure-contrib and swank-clojure on both sides.

You can also setup the path inside emacs by consing the "." to swank-clojure-classpath.